# Simple Gate test redirects to unauthorized page all the time

Tags: laravel

I have a simple Gate in `AuthServiceProvider`:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();
 
    Gate::define('test', function (User $user) {
        return true;
    });
}
```

Then I'm trying to test it on `web.php`:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->middleware('can:test')
```

but it redirects me to the unauthorized page, why?
The `User` model exists, but I just return `true` anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Gate` and `can` middleware first requires authenticated request, then it check the gate logic you define

If you are getting unauthorized response even if your gate always returns `true`, it simply means your request came from non-logged-in user